# Javascript: Find corresponding Element and Type for HTML Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

We are doing test automation. I want to find the corresponding Element and Type if it has one. For an html (Data-qa) attribute.

Example in looping through, Element is input, type is radio.

```
<input type="radio" data-qa"product">


function getDataQaAttributes() {
let dataQaElements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-qa]`);
let netList = '';
for (let i = 0; i < dataQaElements.length; i++) {
    let attr = dataQaElements[i].getAttribute(`data-qa`);

    let elementName = ...
    let type = ... // if has one
```

https://dev.to/chriszie/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation-48lm

Comment: Can you be more specific what actually you want do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `console.log(dataQaElements[i])` in the loop and look up in the console (F12), which properties are available. Anyway, it's:

```
let elementName = dataQaElements[i].tagName.toLowerCase()
let type = dataQaElements[i].type
```